# Let prototype function have sub functions with inherited environment

Tags: javascript

Having a prototype object with various functions, mainly to do with canvas. Typically like this:

```
function CanvasPain() {
    ...
}

CanvasPaint.prototype.drawFoo = function(x, y) {
    this.ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    ...
};
```

I have some functions like paintGrid() where I would like to have sub functions – but also being property based objects. (Not sure how to word this.) Example:

```
CanvasPaint.prototype.grid = function() {
    this.paint = function() {
        this.ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
         // Here this.rows should be a property of CanvasPaint.prototype.grid()
         // and not CanvasPaint()
        for (var i = 0; i < this.rows; ++i) {
            ... paint lines
        }
    };
};
```

And then being able to do say for example:

```
var CP = new CP();

// And in some function:
   this.grid.rows = 10;
   this.grid.cols = 10;
   this.grid.paint();
```

Reason for this is to make the code cleaner. As of now I use something like this:

```
function CanvasPain(arg) {
    ...
    this.properties = {};
    this.properties.fig1 = {a:123, b:111};
    this.properties.grid = {
                rows = arg.rows;
                cols = arg.cols;
                live = 1;
    };
}

CanvasPaint.prototype.paintGrid = function() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    this.ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.properties.grid.rows; ++i)
        ...
}

CanvasPaint.prototype.foo = function() {
    this.paintGrid();
}
```

This does not look to good too me. I want to get rid of the *"properties"* object and instead set those properties to the relevant function if there is one. Like rows and columns for grid belongs to the function object *grid*.

**My question is how I can structure this in code such that the grid function can inherit the properties of the mother object?**

If I say `CP.grid = new CP.grid();` it becomes a independent object and looses for `this.cxt` etc. If I do `CP.grid.paint()` without initiating it as a new object it fails by not having a function paint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `paint()` function needs access to both the `CanvasPain` object as well as its own properties such as `rows` and `cols`.

So, with each new `CanvasPain` object you need to create a dedicated `.grid` property:

```
function CanvasPain(arg)
{
  // ...

  // generate grid object
  this.grid = function(p) {
      // return public interface
      return {
          paint: function() {
              p.ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
              for (var i = 0; i < this.rows; ++i) {
                  //... paint lines
              }
          }
      };
  }(this);
}
```

The `p` variable inside your function points to the `CanvasPain` instance.

```
var CP = new CanvasPain();

CP.grid.rows = 10;
CP.grid.cols = 10;
CP.grid.paint();
```

Comment: Nice. Works :) Lint say to wrap it into parenthesis like: `this.grid = (function(p) { ... })(this);`. Could this give any complications? Also: is it OK to say `this.paint = function() { ... } return {paint : this.paint }` instead? (To reduce one level of indentation in the code.)

Comment: @user13500 The extra parenthesis is not required, and no, you can't use `this.paint` inside the function.

Comment: I'm perhaps miss communicating. What I mean is something like this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=F92SrRLW - it works in my quick tests, but there might be some other complications.

Comment: @user13500 It's better to do `var paint = function() { ... }` and then `return { paint: paint };` then.